# Freemarker : nested templates

Tags: java, freemarker

I am a beginner with freemarker and I would like to use it to generate some repetitive code.

From a simple class like this one:

```
public class Point {
  private Integer x;
  private Integer y;
  private String name;
}
```

I need, for each attribute, to generate lines like this:

```
ValueProvider<Point,Integer> x();
ValueProvider<Point,Integer> y();
ValueProvider<Point,String> name();
```

To achieve this, I have this simple template :

```
ValueProvider<${clazz},${attrType}> ${attrName}();
```

Then, I want to generate a complete class like this:

```
public final class PointValueProviders {

  public interface PointPropertyAccess extends PropertyAccess<Point>{
    ValueProvider<Point,Integer> x();
    ValueProvider<Point,Integer> y();
    ValueProvider<Point,String> name();
  }

  public static final PointPropertyAccess POINT_PA= GWT.create(PointPropertyAccess.class);

  private PointValueProviders(){}

};
```

For this, I have a problem : I don't know how to apply the small templates an undetermined number of times in a bigger template like this one:

```
public final ${clazz}ValueProviders {

  public interface ${clazz}PropertyAccess extends PropertyAccess<${clazz}>{

  //Here, How do I tell freemarker to use the small template???

  //ValueProvider<${clazz},${attrType}> ${attrName}();
  //ValueProvider<${clazz},${attrType}> ${attrName}();
  //ValueProvider<${clazz},${attrType}> ${attrName}();
  //ValueProvider<${clazz},${attrType}> ${attrName}();
  //etc..

  }

  public static final ${clazz}PropertyAccess ${clazzUpperCase}_PA= GWT.create(${clazz}PropertyAccess.class);

  private ${clazz}ValueProviders(){}

};
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are to display some data that you provide to them. So the important question is, how would the template know what `class`/`attrType`/`attrName` trios to output? You should provide a list of those, let's call it `props`, and then just loop through it with

```
<#list props as prop>
   ValueProvider<${prop.clazz},${prop.attrType}> ${prop.attrName}();
</#list>
```

Otherwise to create small reusable templates either use `#macro` (this one is the more flexible) or `#include`. See them in the [FreeMarker Manual](http://freemarker.org/docs/index.html).

Comment: I applied the solution with the list. I added an Entry<"props", List<Map<String,String>>> in the datamodel then I used your template. It worked nice :)